# Find all primes different from three for which $(3|p)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

Find all primes different from three for which

> > $(3|p)=1$, where
> >
> > $(3|p)$ denotes the Ligendre symbol.

Comment: Have you ever heard of quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: Dont understand how to say about $p$ from that relation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$. Then quadratic reciprocity says $(3|p)=(p|3)$ and it's equal to $1$ iff $p\equiv 1\mod 3$. It follows that $p\equiv 1 \mod 12$.

Suppose $p\equiv -1 \mod 4$. Then quadratic reciprocity says $(3|p)=-(p|3)$ and it's equal to $1$ iff $p\equiv -1\mod 3$. It follows that $p\equiv -1 \mod 12$.

So primes you are looking for are ones of the form $12k\pm 1$.

Comment: $(p|3)=1$ iff $p=3k+1$? how?

Comment: @dfahfibdh By definition, $(p|3)=1$ iff $3\nmid p$ and there exists $x$ such that $x^2\equiv p\mod 3$. If $p\equiv 1$, it's enough to take $x=1$. If $p\equiv -1$, there is no such $x$.

Comment: @ Wojowu.... not getting ....

Comment: @dfahfibdh Do you even understand the definition of Legendre's symbol? If not, then I wonder why you ask so specific question about it.

Answer (score 1):

By quadratic reciprocity we have $(3/p)=(p/3)$ if and only if $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$, and 
 $(3/p)=-(p/3)$ if and only if $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$. Then $(p/3)=1$ if $p\equiv 1\bmod 3$, and 
$(p/3)=-1$ if $p\equiv 2\bmod 3$. This means $(3/p)=1$ if either $p\equiv 1\bmod 3$, $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, or $p\equiv 2\bmod 3$, $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$. In other words,
$(p/3)=1$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1\bmod 12$.